# ODE of Second order in python

Tags: python, ode

```
import  sympy  as  sym
sym.init_printing() 
import  scipy  as  sp
import  matplotlib  as  mpl 
import  matplotlib.pyplot  as  plt
#%%
x  =  sym.symbols('x') 
f,  g  =  sym.symbols('f  g',  cls=sym.int)

# f''+ 30000*f'+ 100000000*f = 0.001
# f(0) = 0 e f'(0) = 0
diffeq  =  sym.Eq(f(x).diff(x,  x)  +  (30000)*f(x).diff(x)  +  (100000000)*f(x), sym.(0.001))
 
soln  =  sym.dsolve(diffeq,f(x))

constants = sym.solve([soln.rhs.subs(x,0) - 0, soln.rhs.diff(x,1).subs(x,0)- 0])

C1, C2 = sym.symbols('C1,C2')
soln = soln.subs(constants)

func = sym.lambdify(x,soln.rhs,'numpy')
#%% 
#ploting the solution f(x)
xx  =  sp.arange(-1,1,.01)  
y  =  func(xx)
plt.figure(1) 
plt.plot(xx,y);
```

Hi! I want to solve this ODE of second order in python but it seems I'm doing something wrong.
f'' means the second derivate of f(x)
f' means the first derivate of f(x)

Comment: Giving just one floating point number will cause all intermediary values to be reduced to floating point. This can cause terms that should cancel to not cancel completely. So do not do this, use 1/1000 with the rational data type instead.

Comment: I did what you said but still got the error alert.. Any tips?

Comment: What error alert? Please add this to the question to make it complete.